# Updating a value in a CSV file using CSV module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm building an Employee management system. I want to keep track of all the times an Employee enters and consequently exits the office. I'm reading and writing data using a csv file.

Below is the code:

```
Class Employee:
    def __init__(self, self.name, self.ID, self.EntryTime=None, self.Exittime=None)
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.EntryTime = EntryTime
        self.ExitTime = ExitTime
   def entry(self):
       self.ID = input("Enter your ID:)
       self.key = input("Enter your key: )
       # If ID and key match. Didn't write that part for simplicity.
       self.EntryTime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
       self.ExitTime = None
       # Entering Employee's entry into a register.
       with open("Register.csv", "a", newline="") as register_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(register_file, delimiter=",")
            csv_writer.writerow([self.name, self.ID, self.EntryTime, self.ExitTime])
```

Next when the exit function is called I want to change the ExitTime of a particular entry from None to that ExitTime. Below is what I've tried so far.

```
def exit(self):
       self.ID = input("Enter your ID:)
       # If self.EntryTime is not None. Didn't write that part for simplicity.
       self.key = input("Enter your key: )
       # If ID and key match. Didn't write that part for simplicity.
       self.ExitTime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
       # Updating the exit time in register.
       r = csv.reader(open("Register.csv"))
       lines = list(r)
            for lst in range(len(lines)):
                if lines[lst][1] == self.ID and lines[lst][2] == self.EntryTime:
                    lines[lst][3] = self.ExitTime
                    break
       writer = csv.writer(open("Register.csv", "w"))
       writer.writerows(lines)
```

But for some reason the Exit Time values doesn't change when the exit function is called. Why that might be?

Comment: Because the code has invalid syntax, it can't run and therefore can't update a CSV file. You wrote `Class` instead of `class` and there are unmatched quotes, and the indentation is wrong.

Comment: I might have done some mistake while writing the code here because I just wanted to get my point across i.e the problem with Exit Time not updating.

Answer (score 0):

It is becasue type of `self.EntryTime`  is datetime, but `lines[lst][2]` is string. You can change the condition to

```
if lines[lst][1] == self.ID and lines[lst][2] == str(self.EntryTime):
                lines[lst][3] = self.ExitTime
                break
```